# Manage my Azure Cloud Services using native C# API?

Tags: c#, api, rest, azure

I would like to manage my Azure Cloud Services programmatically.

I am aware of the REST API but I am wondering if the is a native C# API available just like there is with Azure Storage.

REST API - Operations on Hosted Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460812.aspx

Or do I need to wrap the REST API myself as described in the post below?

Azure - Cannot programmatically perform VIP Swap: [Azure - Cannot programmatically perform VIP Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460305/azure-cannot-programmatically-perform-vip-swap)

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

The CSManage suggestion helped me a lot.

You can reuse the ServiceManagement project and write your own client (instead of CSManage).

Use the ServiceManagementHelper to setup a channel to execute the commands.

Example:

```
    public static string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public static string CertificateThumbprint { get; set; }

    public static X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SubscriptionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionId"];
        CertificateThumbprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateThumbprint"];

        X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, CertificateThumbprint, false);
        if (certs.Count != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Client certificate cannot be found. Please check the config file. ");
            return;
        }
        Certificate = certs[0];

        // List Hosted Services
        var channel = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel("WindowsAzureEndPoint", Certificate);
        var lhs = channel.ListHostedServices(SubscriptionId);
        foreach (HostedService hs in lhs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(hs.ServiceName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a very similar requirement and unfortunately there is no wrapper that lets you do this, the one mentioned in the other answer only has table/blob/queue support.

However there is a neat solution called csmanage, it's a command prompt application that uses the REST API under the hood lets you manage pretty much anything on Azure; you can view the source and see how it's done and how to implement it yourself.

[Link to CSManage on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c)

*Word of warning*: it's quite a task to grasp the flow of the application but once you get going, it gets easier.

Hint: Have a look at `CSManageCommand.cs` on line 104 is where the magic starts to happen, they're using WCF to communicate with the API which you can see in `app.config`.

If you're looking to use certain known command you can see they're presented in the following classes:

[image]

Comment: you can manage VMs through their commandlet API, or you can use the Azure CLI tool (written in Node) to manage VMs. That's what I use.

Comment: Thanks, it look like csmanage is what I need. Now all I have to do is understand the code... :-)

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2013 there is a set of C# libraries that wrap the Windows Azure Service Management REST API.

It's available in nuget under the package name [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.libraries).

The blog posts [here](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries) and [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2014/04/wamlmaml/) give a bit of an overview and the documentation can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx).

As the question asks, these libraries allow you to manage services (create deployments, scale deployments, perform vip swaps etc.) rather than interact with blob / table storage.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look at the [Azure Fluent Management Library](http://nuget.org/packages/Elastacloud.AzureManagement.Fluent). There is a NuGet package available.

Comment: Do you know if the source code of Azure Fluent Management Library is available somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is current with the nuget package, but you can find the source at https://github.com/azurecoder/fluent-management.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a Windows Azure API for C# and .NET.

You can find their Github page [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net) and documentation [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/).

Comment: Yes, I use this one for Azure storage but it is missing all the other stuff.

Comment: again, you'll have to look in to the Node based CLI or the commandlets API or something else to accomplish that.