# how to access the monitoring data of Azure websites outside the management portal

Tags: azure

I want to access the monitoring data for my website, that you see in the management portal under monitoring tab, outside the management portal.

Is is possible?? If yes then how? I don't want to invest in a third party tool. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to then implement a solution utilizing the REST API using the programming language of your choice.

You can read more about the implementation of the API here : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx)

In short :

> The Service Management API provides programmatic access to much of the functionality available through the Management Portal.
>   The Service Management API is a REST API. All API operations are performed over SSL and mutually authenticated using X.509 v3 certificates.

Here is an answer I have previously posted, it's a good starting point using the API in the C# environment, it has examples for most use-cases. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495152/manage-my-azure-cloud-services-using-native-c-sharp-api/13495418#13495418)