# Making app that receives azure subscription data

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-api-management

I need to make an app that allows to log in specific azure account and then see what subscriptions there are and what's the status of them.

I cannot figure out from what can I start to make it.
I think I must use azure API, but I can't understand where I can get an Azure API key etc.

Can anybody give me some advice?

Appreciate any kind of help ;)

Comment: check this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495152/manage-my-azure-cloud-services-using-native-c-sharp-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar using the [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/), which to me was easier than calling the API directly.

The SDK requires the same OAuth token as the API.  You can use the ADAL library to obtain the required token.  [This article](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/12/calling-arm-using-plain-rest.html) was helpful for getting authentication working.